# Docker client communicating with docker host

Tags: docker

I have a docker daemon installed in UbuntuA machine.

I am using UbuntuB machine as the docker client.
I know that UbuntuA machine has the docker daemon installed and can do operations as well.

But I am not getting on which port it is running.
I am using this command :
sudo docker -H tcp://127.0.0.1:5555 -d &

and after this , when I use the following command:
 sudo docker -H tcp://127.0.0.1:5555 info

I am getting an error : docker daemon not found .
How to find out on which port , the daemon is running?

Comment: Are you using *UbuntuB* to contact *UbuntuA* with 127.0.0.1?

Comment: No.  from UbuntuB it will be :$sudo docker -H tcp:UbuntuA:5555 info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `-H tcp://127.0.0.1:5555` docker daemon option on the UbuntuA machine will instruct docker to bind to the loopback network interface (127.0.0.1). As a result it will only accept connections originating from the UbuntuA machine.

If you want to accept connections incoming from any network interface use `-H tcp://0.0.0.0:5555`. Be aware that anyone that would be able to connect to your UbuntuA machine on port 5555 will be able to control your docker host. You need to protect it with firewall rules to allow only UbuntuB to connect to UbuntuA on port 5555.

Comment: You can set the default config for this in /etc/default/docker

Comment: You could also use the `--net=host` run parameter so the container has full access to the host's network interfaces. But this has also some side-effects you might not want. More info here: [Docker Networking](https://docs.docker.com/articles/networking/)